# Getting Intent Filter to work for App

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to make it so whenever someone clicks an address or launches geo intent filter it gives the option to open my application as well to show an activity with mapview of geo location. I was just wondering if this was possible?

Would I just make an activity, add a mapview and have the data passed in from intent (geo loc) passed in to map and refresh it?

Also how do I access the screen to have the option to choose my map view app over googles, etc.

I found this intent filter which I believe is doing what I need:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="maps.google.com" />
    <data android:scheme="geo" />
</intent-filter>
```

but not sure how to launch that intent to test if my app shows up.

Answer (score 0):

create an html page

write this in

```
<html><head></head><body>



<a href="intent://maps.google.com/#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.mypackage.myapp;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;launchFlags=268435456;l.some_long_param=12768;S.some_string_param=open2@email.com;D.some_double_param=1.2;end;">open my app</a>
</body></html>
```

click this link from an android web browser that has the app installed

if the app is installed, it will open the chooser, not asking the user to choose

if the app is not installed, it will open the google play at the index of the package name